# How to set the base URL in Drupal 8

Tags: migration, drupal-8

I just completed back up and migrate in D8 for the first time.
The issue is that images are not displaying in target site.

Source site is at root of `public_html`.

Target site is at `public_html/folder/sub_folder`.

I had a block like this:

```html
<img src="/sites/default/files/imgs/fb_logo.png" alt="fb" height="50" width="50">
```

When I go to target site, I can not see the image.  It is because because images in target site are pointing to `public_html/folder` directory but instead it should point to `public_html/folder/sub_folder`.

To fix it, I updated the `settings.php` file by adding the base URL but did not fix the issue:

```
$base_url = 'example.com/sub_folder';
```

`example.com` here is another d8 site pointing to `public_html/folder`.

My site is pointing to `public_html/folder/sub_folder`.

How can I add the base URL to point my site to sub_folder?

Answer (score 1):

$base_url is no more on Drupal 8.

```
$host = \Drupal::request()->getHost();
$host = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost();
```

Answer (score -1):

There are many way to **get** the base url. You can use one of shortest way to assign `$base_url` is:

```
global $base_url;

drupal_set_message('<img src="'.$base_url.'/sites/default/files/imgs/fb_logo.png" alt="fb" height="50" width="50">');
```